# (OCaml) How does "remove" function from OCaml's PriorityQueue look like?

Tags: queue, ocaml

Does anyone know how does the "remove" function from OCaml's PriorityQueue library look like?

I know how it works but I just wanna see the code.

Thanks!

Comment: ocaml comes with no PriorityQueue library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're talking about the PriorityQueue module from Holger Arnold's ocaml-base library? Just look at the source, it's this:

```
let remove h x = 
  try remove_index h (Hashtbl.find h.indices x)
  with Not_found -> ()
```